# How to use the CSV MIME-type?

Tags: php, csv, http-headers, mime

In a web application I am working on, the user can click on a link to a CSV file.  There is no header set for the mime-type, so the browser just renders it as text.  I would like for this file to be sent as a .csv file, so the user can directly open it with calc, excel, gnumeric, etc.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
echo "cell 1, cell 2";
```

This code works as expected on my computer (Isn't that how it always is?) but does not work on another computer.

My browser is a nightly build of FF 3.0.1 (on linux).  The browsers it did not work in were IE 7 and FF 3.0 (on windows)

Are there any quirks I am unaware of?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

You could try to force the browser to open a "Save As..." dialog by doing something like:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv');
echo "cell 1, cell 2";
```

Which should work across most major browsers.

Answer (score 12):

You are not specifying a language or framework, but the following header is used for file downloads:

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.csv"
```

Answer (score 5):

With Internet Explorer you often have to specify the Pragma: public header as well for the download to function properly..

```
header('Pragma: public');
```

Just my 2 cents..

Comment: Pragma: public has no meaning whatsoever for Internet Explorer. (I worked on the component in question, and I grepped the source).

Comment: Possibly the actual utility of this is to replace a preexisting Pragma: no-cache header?

Answer (score 2):

This code can be used to export any file, including csv

```
// application/octet-stream tells the browser not to try to interpret the file
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($data));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
```

Comment: "octetstream" is meant to be "octet-stream"

Comment: This can cause a warning in some browsers: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `text/csv` but it did not work for me after that tried different stuff and I figured out that if we use this `text/plain`. Now the file upload is completed. as expected. This problem was in the Yii2 file upload widget.

Example response after success.

```
{"files":[{"name":"unit_ids list - Sheet1.csv","type":"text/plain","size":30,"base_url":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.abc.co","path":"1/g2qVy3JtyZBLaRUd8c5gMOtSyrTEwdzR.csv","url":"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.abc.co/1/g2qVy3JtyZBLaRUd8c5gMOtSyrTEwdzR.csv","delete_url":"/coupons/default/sheet-delete?path=1%2Fg2qVy3JtyZBLaRUd8c5gMOtSyrTEwdzR.csv"}]}
```