# How do I import CSV to mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a list of csv files, which I want to be import to mysql db, using codeigniter.

I tried `$this->load->library('getcsv');` library but how to import the csv without uploading the CSV files to the server, what I meant was just uploading the files to a temp location like how pure coding PHP does.

Any idea?

**Example:**

I wanted something like this.

**HTML:**`<input type="file" name="csv" />`

to a temp string

**Codeigniter:**   `$this->input->upload['tmp_name']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave exactly the answer for this. Take a look at this answer of mine for your problem's solution.

This will generate report in CSV format.

[Reports in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189021/reports-in-codeigniter/11189368#11189368)

And this will tell you how to read and dump csv files.

[Codeigniter REST CSV import to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337221/codeigniter-rest-csv-import-to-mysql/11339125#11339125)

Comment: your solution seems to be nice, but how do i upload a CSV to a temp location etc and use it?

Comment: for this purpose you will have to use file upload

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `contacts`;
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contact_first` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_last` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(255) character set latin1 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

import.php::

```
<?php  

//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect); //select the table 
// 

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html> 

//get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts_tmp (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the default_controller value in route.php which lies inside config folder.

$route['default_controller'] = "csv";

Create a controller as **csv.php**

```
<?php
class csv extends CI_Controller
{
    public $data;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('csv_model');
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('uploadCsvView',$data);
    }
    function uploadData()
    {
        $this->csv_model->uploadData();
        redirect('csv');
    }
}
?>
```

And create a model as **csv_model.php**

```
<?php
class csv_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function uploadData()
    {
        $count=0;
        $fp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r') or die("can't open file");
        while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024))
        {
            $count++;
            if($count == 1)
            {
                continue;
            }//keep this if condition if you want to remove the first row
            for($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++)
            {
                $insert_csv = array();
                $insert_csv['id'] = $csv_line[0];//remove if you want to have primary key,
                $insert_csv['empName'] = $csv_line[1];
                $insert_csv['empAddress'] = $csv_line[2];

            }
            $i++;
            $data = array(
                'id' => $insert_csv['id'] ,
                'empName' => $insert_csv['empName'],
                'empAddress' => $insert_csv['empAddress'],
            $data['crane_features']=$this->db->insert('tableName', $data);
        }
        fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
        $data['success']="success";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

And at last create a view as **uploadCsvView.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url();?>csv/uploadData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Choose your file: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="userfile" id="userfile"  align="center"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-9">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

And create mysql table where data is going to be inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(
    id INT,
    empName VARCHAR( 100 ) ,
    empAddress VARCHAR( 100 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And most important point:

> MySql and Csv file should both be same

Sample csv data is in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-OuLrage4PpUmtKNkhuS1JrSkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Already answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537243/how-to-import-csv-in-database-using-codeigniter-php/39244744#39244744)