# Generate CSV file using PHP Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to generate a csv file, using data from a database. How does one do this in PHP CodeIgniter framework?

Comment: This might help, once you have your query turned into an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251625/how-to-create-and-download-a-csv-file-from-php-script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reports in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189021/reports-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer of mine and you will know exactly how you can do it.

[Reports in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189021/reports-in-codeigniter/11189368#11189368)

You need to use [Codeigniter Database Utility Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html)

And need to return query instead of `result_array` or `result`

Comment: I used Reports in codeigniter link code but it does not updating my csv. I mentioned CSV file path like this

    write_file(base_url().'public/csv_file.csv',$new_report);

Comment: what do you want to do? generate new csv file or update the existing one

Comment: I want to generate new csv

Comment: where i have to write this function csv_from_result($report), this was mentioned in codeigniter controller like $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report);

Comment: this need to be written in controller as mentioned in example. Just you have to give the correct path. use constant `APPPATH` and concat where you want to write file

Comment: Thanks man it works fine but is it posible to create new csv file at everytime

Comment: why not. every time when ever this controller method is called you need to give new name or you can generate a random name like this `'generated_csv_'.time().'csv'`. this will always generate file with new name due to php `time()`.

Comment: dont you think answer should be accepted

Comment: write_file(APPPATH . 'generated_csv_'.time().'csv',$new_report);

I used this but not generating any new file

Comment: it should be something like this `write_file(APPPATH . '/views/csv/'.'generated_csv_'.time().'csv',$new_report)`

Comment: Sorry its not working

Comment: please search how you can fix path problem

Comment: Okay i will check but everything looks write.

Comment: Now all problem solved working great Thank You very much

Comment: @Serma don't you think an answer should be accepted or voted up

Answer (score 1):

```
function query_to_csv( $query, $filename, $attachment = false, $headers = true) {

    if($attachment) {
        // send response headers to the browser
        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    } else {
        $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($headers) {
        // output header row (if at least one row exists)
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($row) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row));
            // reset pointer back to beginning
            mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        }
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` and OP used Codeigniter, not core php.