# ci csv file upload to database but page not found

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

the view, as an action after choosing and submitting the file it calls the csv/importcsv.

```
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>csv/importcsv"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="userfile" ><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
```

this is where i think the error happens, and i have tried changing the path of the file time and time again but still does not work, sorry new to ci, i'm just following some tutorial sites and trying to understand their codes.

the model

`

class Csv_model extends CI_Model {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

}

function get_sampledb() {
    $query = $this->db->get('sampledb');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function insert_csv($data) {
    $this->db->insert('sampledb', $data);
}
```

}
?>`

the controller

`

class Csv extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('csv_model');
    $this->load->library('csvimport');
}

function index() {
    $data['sampledb'] = $this->csv_model->get_sampledb();
    $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
}

function importcsv() {
    $data['sampledb'] = $this->csv_model->get_sampledb();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    } else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'first_name'=>$row['first_name'],
                    'last_name'=>$row['last_name'],
                    'item_name'=>$row['item_name'],
                    'item_price'=>$row['item_price'],
                    'item_quantity'=>$row['item_quantity'],
                    'email_ad'=>$row['email_ad'],
                    'phone_num'=>$row['phone_num'],
                    'shipping_cost'=>$row['cost'],
                );
                $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'csv');
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
        } else
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    }
```

}
/*END OF FILE*/
?>`

as for the library i downloaded something from github, i copied and pasted it at application/libraries/csv/csvimport.php as said in the tutorial, i dont know whats happening. my main concern is in the view file, its returning a page not found after uploading,is my path wrong?when looking at firebug it can parse the data of the csv file but cannot save it due to the page not found, is my path wrong?thanks

Comment: [Reports in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189021/reports-in-codeigniter/11189368#11189368)

Comment: thanks for the reply @raheelshan but this is upload