# Convert the result Set into Database Object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to write a CSV in Codeignter for a result set fetched from db.

I am already using the solution mentioned here. [Reports in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189021/reports-in-codeigniter/11189368#11189368)

But the issue is that it writes the whole table. Now I want to fetch and write specific records. So here is my model code.

```
    $where = "hangtag_spoc_number = 2202";
    $result = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('hangtag_request')
            ->where($where)
            ->get()
            ->result_array();
    return $result;
```

It gives me this error.

```
You must submit a valid result object
```

If I change the model code to this

```
    return $query = $this->db->get('hangtag_request');
```

It works perfectly. Is there any way I can make my model code to return the results in the form of DB object? Coz it seems thats the form we need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need result object then you shouldn't use the `result_array()`

```
$this->db->get();
```

The above statement runs the selection query and returns the result.It does return in form that can be used for presentation.

```
result_array()
```

This function returns the query result as an array, or an empty array when no result is produced.

Its good to use `return $query = $this->db->get('hangtag_request');` for obtaining result object.

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved.

Just had to remove result_array() so the correct code becomes

```
$where = "hangtag_spoc_number = 2202";
$result = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('hangtag_request')
        ->where($where)
        ->get();
return $result;
```