# How to export to xlsx and word file using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to export data to xlsx and word using CI ? help me please

```
if (preg_match('/MSIE ([\d\.]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches)) {  
                $version = $matches[1];  
                $problematicMimes = array('text/plain', 'text/html');  
                if (($version <= 5.5) && in_array($mimetype, $problematicMimes)) {  
                    $mimetype = 'application/download';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Excel file using PHP Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441221/create-excel-file-using-php-codeigniter)