# Ruby - open-uri doesn't download a file itself, but just the HTML code of the website

Tags: ruby, curl, open-uri, curb

I am trying to use this snippet:

```
  open("data.csv", "wb") do |file|
    file << open("https://website.com/data.php", http_basic_authentication: ["username", "password"]).read
  end
```

But instead of the desired CSV file, I get just downloaded the HTML code of the website. What's the problem?
When I access the URL and I am not logged in, then it's displayed the form for login (not the HTTP authentication window).
How to solve this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share more data about the request to the website? I think that the request is not being formed correctly.

Comment: When I access **https://website.com/data.php** and I am not logged in, I am redirected on the page that is on this url - **https://website.com/login.php?go=data.php**. I was talking with admin and he told me that this can be solved with CURL (in PHP). So I am looking for the way to do it in Ruby.

Comment: your code in ruby is OK IF and only IF Content mime type is text/plain

Comment: it's just a pbm of mime type in header , if you canno't change it, you have to parse output

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try out **net/http** http://dzone.com/snippets/how-download-files-ruby

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your php script return a response with a mime-type different of text/plain or better : text/csv

please see this related previous response

[How to use the CSV MIME-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398237/how-to-use-the-csv-mime-type)

in the PHP Script :

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=data.csv');
```

Comment: In the **data.php** script is generated CSV files. When I download this file manually, it's the classic CSV file. It's not my website nor my script, I am fetching these data form a supplier.