# Impossible to fire CSV file download from Ajax query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, download

I want to fire a download window from an Ajax query.

The Ajax query is launched when I click on a button on my page.

**Here is the Ajax query (function called on click on the button):**

```
function exportDetailOuvrage(idData){

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ouvrage.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { typeOuvrage : idData },
        success : function (data){
            $('body').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Here is the PHP code to generate the CSV:**

```
<?php

$csv = "Town;Name;Code\r\n" ;

foreach($result as $row){

    $csv .= $row['town'].";".$row['name'].";".$row['code']."\r\n" ;

}

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");

echo $csv;

?>
```

In the PHP code, `$result` is an array built on a SQL query in a database.

The CSV string is generated as wanted, the server answer is 200 (no errors using firebug). I have checked the sent parameters and the CSV string returned: everyting is OK.

**The only issue is that no download window appears and no data.csv file is saved...**

I was wondering if my Ajax code, especially the content of `success` parameter is good. I don't know what to put exactly inside this parameter.

---

**EDIT :**

According to @MonkeyZeus answer and comments, here is the content of my `gimme_file.php`:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
    readfile($_SESSION['I_CAN_DOWNLOAD_ONLY_THIS']);

    exit;

?>
```

I get the following error message inside the `data.csv` downloaded file:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: I_CAN_DOWNLOAD_ONLY_THIS in <b>D:\STAT\modele\gimme_file.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in <b>D:\STAT\modele\gimme_file.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
```

Comment: Look in your browser's console. Are you seeing a proper request / response?

Comment: Yes indeed! Request and response are perfectly filled. The issue really seems to be about firing the download window...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download CSV file using "AJAX"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346072/download-csv-file-using-ajax) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396580/ajax-and-downloading-csv-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051215/ajax-call-to-download-a-csv-file).  You get the idea. Do some basic searching first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript (jQuery) can absolutely **NOT** trigger a file download natively; it would be a gigantic security issue.

What you must do is the following:

1. Call the CSV generator
2. Save the CSV to the server with a unique name
3. Pass this unique name to your `success:` callback
4. Use `window.location` to redirect the browser to the CSV file

---

My apologies if my post is very terse but I just do not want you to chase your tail for hours trying to achieve something that is fundamentally blocked by web browsers.

---

**jQuery**

```
function exportDetailOuvrage(idData){

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ouvrage.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { typeOuvrage : idData },
        success : function (data){
            window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/gimme_file.php';
        }
    });
}
```

**ouvrage.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$csv = "Town;Name;Code\r\n" ;

foreach($result as $row){

    $csv .= $row['town'].";".$row['name'].";".$row['code']."\r\n" ;

}

$filename = 'ouvrage_'.uniqid('', TRUE).'.csv';

file_put_contents($filename, $csv);

$_SESSION['I_CAN_DOWNLOAD_ONLY_THIS'] = $filename;

?>
```

**gimme_file.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
readfile($_SESSION['I_CAN_DOWNLOAD_ONLY_THIS']);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus! I tried your code and it seems to improve. I get the following error messages inside the downloaded CSV: (1) `Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:\STAT\modele\gimme_file.php` and (2) `readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in D:\STAT\modele\gimme_file.php`. What do you expect to put inside `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @wiltomap It sounds like you forgot `session_start();` like I showed in my examples.

Comment: No, I did mention it in `gimme_file.php`! That's why the error messages seem strange... Any idea on the origin of this issue? I'm so close to it now. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @wiltomap Please update your question and add the code from `gimme_file.php`. Also, please mention which line number the error message is pointing to. Also, according to the error that you commented I am going to guess that you are missing a dollar symbol in front of `_SESSION`

Comment: @wiltomap interesting, so your `ouvrage.php` is the same as my example as well?

Comment: I had forgotten the `session_start();` at the beginning of `ouvrage.php` file... It seems to work nicely at present! I have lots of PHP files for my website, would you advice me to put a `session_start();` at the top of each file? Or is it just necessary for the `$_SESSION` variable?

Comment: Correct, it is only necessary for the `$_SESSION` variable. If you ever want to build a site with user credentials and a login page then you will need to understand `session_start();` at a much deeper level. The solution I provided in my answer is basically a band-aid fix.