# laravel adding .txt on the downloaded file

Tags: csv, laravel, download

im trying to give the user ability to download a specific file. here is my code.

but it keeps adding .txt after the file is downloaded which I want is a .csv

```
public function downloadCSVSample()
    {

        $file= public_path(). "/downloads/SampleCSV.csv";
        $headers = array(
              'Content-Type: application/csv',
            );
        return Response::download($file, 'SampleCSV.csv', $headers);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your browser can't interpret the file. According to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398237/how-to-use-the-csv-mime-type), you need to force it to open 'save as...' dialog:

```php
$headers = array(
          'Content-Type: text/csv',
          'Content-disposition: attachment'
);
```

Comment: hmm still adding the .txt.

Comment: I tested your code and it works perfectly (get .csv file). take a look at this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398237/how-to-use-the-csv-mime-type/15291827#15291827

Comment: tested it to another browser and works perfectly fine.