# Laravel 5.7 Storage download CSV file adds a .txt extension

Tags: php, laravel, csv

In Laravel 5.7 I'm using a simple route to allow a user to download a local stored csv file.

```
Route::get('download/{file}', function($file) {
            return Storage::disk('s3')->download($file, $file, ['Content-Type: text/csv"']);
           })->name('download');
```

And in my Blade template :

```
<a href="{{ Route('download', ['file' => 'import.csv']) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-line btn-rect" data-original-title="" title=""> <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

When user clicks on the link, Laravel is finding import.csv file into s3 disk and allow user to download the file but it adds a .txt extension. So the user is downloading import.csv.txt and this file corresponds to import.csv data.

How can I prevent Laravel to add a .txt extension to the CSV file ? I tried `return Storage::disk('s3')->download($file, $file);` and `return Storage::disk('s3')->download($file);` and same result each time.

**Running environment**: This is a production server running Apache2 with PHP 7.1 under Debian 9.

**EDIT1**: I've made the same test on a fresh Laravel 5.7 install, same issue :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return Storage::disk('public')->download('import.csv', 'import.csv', ['Content-Type: text/csv"','Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv']);});
```

**EDIT2**: I've added a new test with a controller.
Route :

```
Route::get('test', 'test@test');
```

Controller `test` :

```
public function test()
{
  return Storage::disk('public')->download('import.csv', 'import.csv', ['Content-Type: text/csv"','Content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyVerySpecial.csv']);
}
```

Exactly the same result

**EDIT3**: Tested with headers:

```
['Content-Type: application/octet-stream"','Content-disposition: attachment;filename="MyVerySpecial.csv"']
```

Same result

**EDIT4**: Looks to be a server configuration problem as I have this issue with Firefox (last developer edition) and not with IE

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT5**: I think there is something wrong with Laravel because if I'm creating a php file with:

```
<?php
$file = "../storage/app/public/import.csv";
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
readfile ($file);
exit();
```

This is working perfectly with Firefox. But if I use a route like

```
return Storage::disk('public')->download('import.csv', 'import.csv', ['Content-Description: File Transfer','Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=/home/webadmin/fresh/storage/app/public/import.csv']);
```

Well it does not work.

**Question**: has somebody else tried to reproduce same issue?

Comment: Did you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825103/laravel-adding-txt-on-the-downloaded-file

Comment: Yes, still have same issue. Please note that I don't want to use a Controller, I just want to use the route function (I'll test with a controller, I've just installed a fresh Laravel 5.7 and same error)

Comment: Can you check the response headers in the browser ? Specially `Content-Type`

Comment: Reponse headers : 
0 Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
1 Content-disposition: attachment;filename="MyVerySpecial.csv"

Comment: Do you use Apache or PHP server built in ?

Comment: This is a production server running Apache2 with PHP 7.1 under Debian 9

Comment: Check the `mime.types` file in your server, find the csv mime type

Comment: In etc/mime.types I found `text/csv     csv`, no other result with 'csv'

Comment: run `apache2 -M` and check the  `mime_module` is loaded, can you test the download in other machine or browser ?

Comment: This is funny, looks like this is a Firefox issue, with IE I'm downloading import.csv

Comment: Result of apache2 -M: mime_module (shared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of this problem is format used for headers :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Storage::disk('public')->download('import.csv', 'import.csv', ['Content-Description' =>  'File Transfer','Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream','Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=import.csv']);
});
```

This is a good way how to send headers to download files, tested on Firefox and IE and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all these headers :

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($data));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
```

Comment: I've addded these headers (not the Content-Length as I dont't have the file object when I'm accessing to the route), same result (see my edits)

Comment: Try to make like it's explain in docs : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#file-downloads
So, get the file path, and then `return response()->download($pathToFile);`

Comment: Same result with `return response()->download('storage/import.csv', 'import.csv', ['Content-Type: application/octet-stream"','Content-disposition: attachment;filename="MyVerySpecial.csv"']);`