# error message after converting datatable to excel in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

error message after converting datatable to excel in asp.net c#

below code i am using

```
 Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    string str = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
    {
        Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
        str = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\n");
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        str = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
            str = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
    }
    Response.End();
```

error message is

```
  ![Your trying to open different format or corrupted file ][2]
```

[image]

its opening after clicking ok but i dnt want showing this message ....
where i made error...
thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content type is wrong. You are creating a CSV output, not Excel. Change content type to text/csv and file extension to .csv.

[How to use the CSV MIME-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398237/how-to-use-the-csv-mime-type)

Link to OpenXML SDK which let's you create any Office format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: could pls tell me how can i generate excel ?